# How to aggregate multiple objects with same values in certain fields?

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    CONNECTION_CHOICES = [
        ('REST-API', 'REST-API'),
        ('SSH', 'SSH'),
        ('SFTP', 'SFTP'),
        ('SOAP-API', 'SOAP-API'),
    ]
    endpoint = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)
    port = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    connection_type = models.CharField(max_length=240, choices=CONNECTION_CHOICES)
    source_tool = models.ForeignKey(Tool, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='source-tool+')
    target_tool = models.ForeignKey(Tool, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='target-tool+')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.source_tool.name + " to " + self.target_tool.name 
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tools:connection-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In a view, I am trying to combine objects, where source_tool and target_tool are the same, but the connection_type differs.

Currently, I have this view:

```
def api_map_view(request):
    json = {}
    nodes = []
    links = []
    connections = Connection.objects.all()

    for connection in connections:
        if {'name': connection.source_tool.name, 'id': connection.source_tool.id} not in nodes:
            nodes.append({'name': connection.source_tool.name, 'id': connection.source_tool.id})
        if {'name': connection.target_tool.name, 'id': connection.target_tool.id} not in nodes:
            nodes.append({'name': connection.target_tool.name, 'id': connection.target_tool.id})
        if {'source': connection.source_tool.id, 'target': connection.target_tool.id} in links:
            links.replace({'source': connection.source_tool.id, 'target': connection.target_tool.id, 'type': links['type'] + '/' + connection_type})
        else:
            links.append({'source': connection.source_tool.id, 'target': connection.target_tool.id, 'type': connection.connection_type})
    json['nodes'] = nodes
    json['links'] = links
    print(json)
    return JsonResponse(data=json)
```

This returns, e.g.

```
{
   'nodes':
           [
               {'name': 'Ansible', 'id': 1 },
               {'name': 'Terraform', 'id': 2},
               {'name': 'Foreman', 'id': 3}
           ],
   'links':
           [
               {'source': 1, 'target': 2, 'type': 'SSH'},
               {'source': 2, 'target': 3, 'type': 'REST-API'}
               {'source': 1, 'target': 2, 'type': 'REST-API'}
           ]
}
```

My usecase is, that I want to modify connections that I do not get 2 different list entries for the same connection, that only differs in the type. Instead of the JSON above, I want to achieve this:

```
{
   'nodes':
           [
               {'name': 'Ansible', 'id': 1 },
               {'name': 'Terraform', 'id': 2},
               {'name': 'Foreman', 'id': 3}
           ],
   'links':
           [
               {'source': 1, 'target': 2, 'type': 'SSH/REST-API'},
               {'source': 2, 'target': 3, 'type': 'REST-API'}
           ]
}
```

Currently I am not able to create a query or modify the list of dicts to find the entry, where source and target are the same as the current entry (iterating through the list), and modify the type-field.

I am using Django 3.1 with Python 3.8.

Regards

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. links is a list, but you treat it as dict in one place with a method "replace", that neither list or dict have. However, you never hit that code, as you append dicts with 3 keys to links and test if links has a dict with 2 keys.

Comment: That was exactly my problem: finding a "subpart" (2 of 3 values) of a dict to modify the third value

Comment: Yeah, I figured later that that was the results of multiple attempts where at one point links was a string. FWIW, I prefer the defaultdict solution (was also making that solution when I saw aneroid working on it). And I wouldn't join the types to string, but keep it a list so the consumer can choose how she wishes to format without having to do splits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs in these lines:

```
if {'source': connection.source_tool.id, 'target': connection.target_tool.id} in links:
    links.replace({'source': connection.source_tool.id, 'target': connection.target_tool.id, 'type': links['type'] + '/' + connection_type})
else:
    links.append({'source': connection.source_tool.id, 'target': connection.target_tool.id, 'type': connection.connection_type})
```

You're checking if `{'source': X, 'target': Y}` is in `links` but for the first occurrence, you're *adding* `{'source': X, 'target': Y, 'type': Z1}` to `links`. So the item you added won't ever be `True` for `in links` since it has an extra key 'type'.

On the other hand, you *can't* check directly for `{'source': X, 'target': Y, 'type': Z1}` in links because then it won't match for then case when `'type': Z2`.

To work around it, do one of:

---

**1.** (preferred) use a dictionary with the keys as a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or just a tuple of source and target. Since tuples and namedtuples are hashable, they can be use as dict keys.

```
import collections  # at the top

links = {}  # links is now a dict, not a list
SourceTarget = collections.namedtuple('SourceTarget', 'source target')
# >>> SourceTarget('X', 'Y')  # to show how they work
# SourceTarget(source='X', target='Y')
```

To be used like:

```
if (connection.source_tool.id, connection.target_tool.id) in links:  # tuples can match with namedtuples
    links[SourceTarget(connection.source_tool.id, connection.target_tool.id)] += '/' + connection.connection_type
else:
    links[SourceTarget(connection.source_tool.id, connection.target_tool.id)] = connection.connection_type
```

And at the end where you want them as a list of objects/dictionaries:

```
json['links'] = [{'source': st.source, 'target': st.target, 'type': type_}
                 for st, type_ in links.items()]
                # I used `type_` so that it doesn't conflict with Python own `type()`
```

---

**2.** (variation of 1) Still need to use a tuple or a namedtuple as your dict keys but then use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `list` to keep appending the connection types.

You won't need the `if/else` part and you can just do:

```
import collections

links = collections.defaultdict(list)
...

# using tuples as the key instead of namedtuples....
links[(connection.source_tool.id, connection.target_tool.id)].append(connection.connection_type)
```

That will either create new entries for each `(source, target)` with that `type` as a single value in a list or it will append to that list. No `if` check needed.

And to convert it to your json obj:

```
json['links'] = [{'source': st[0], 'target': st[1], 'type': '/'.join(types)}
                 for st, types) in links.items()]
```

---

Btw, since you're on **Python 3.8**, you can use [**assignment expressions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#examples) aka the 'walrus operator', to reduce repetition and make code more concise.

Using option 1 as an example, it will make the first parts of your if-block **much more clear**, since it becomes obvious that you're adding the thing if it doesn't exist; without needing to read the whole long line.

```
if (src := {'name': connection.source_tool.name, 'id': connection.source_tool.id}) not in nodes:
    nodes.append(src)
if (trg := {'name': connection.target_tool.name, 'id': connection.target_tool.id}) not in nodes:
    nodes.append(trg)
if (st := (connection.source_tool.id, connection.target_tool.id)) in links:
    # used a tuple to update _existing_ NT element
    links[st] += '/' + connection.connection_type
else:
    # but must use namedtuples when adding new elements
    links[SourceTarget(*st)] = connection.connection_type
```

Comment: Awesome! That was exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I used the first variant and it works like a charm.

Comment: I like the 2nd variant because it uses lists which keep items separate (and not just with a `/`, so if you had to do other checks, it's easier with a list of items `['a', 'b', 'c']` than with a string `a/b/c`. And whether you use tuples or named tuples is really down to use-case and if many tuples are used all over the place and it gets confusing which tuple-type is being operated on. If you use namedtuples, remember to add the keys as namedtuples; even though the keys can be "checked" against tuples, as I've shown above. And the 'only append' without `if/then` means less code & clearer.

Comment: I've added an edit for some code cleanup you can/should do using Python 3.8 assignment expressions. Makes the code much more readable.